# How to move control with keyboard only in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, interface-builder

I'm accessing my Mac remotely with TeamViewer. I can't seem to be able to move a control with the mouse only.

What are the keyboard combinations to do so?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Double click on your object in the sidebar and use the arrow keys.

To move faster, hold the shift key.

Comment: I think it's funny that I answered this question over a year ago.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Still works that way in Xcode 8.

Comment: Saved my bacon!